# Check when my app is in background when back-button and home-button

Tags: android

Hi guys I'm using this method to check if my app is in background or not:

```
public static boolean isApplicationSentToBackground(final Context context) {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    for( RunningTaskInfo rti: tasks ) {
        ComponentName cn = rti.topActivity;
        LogHelper.i(TAG, "Component Name: " + cn.getPackageName() );
    }



    if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
        ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
        if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I'm calling this method in my Activity onPause, onStop, onDestroy
These is my results:

when I'm in my activity and I click the android-home-button it follow this flow:

onPause -> is in background? true
onStop -> is in background? true

and it's all perfect.
The problem is when I click the android-back-button that from th activity goes back to the android home. This is the flow:

onPause -> is in background? false
onStop -> is in background? false
onDestroy -> is in background? false

If you check the code I have a Log cat stamp and it always (in the back-button case) stamp this:

**03-29 00:46:39.324: I/DFFramework(15344): MusicUtils - Component Name: my-activity-name**

This means that my activity is not in the background.
What can I do?

UPDATE:

I'm adding more info about my scenario. I'm developing a Music Player so I've to catch this kind of event in order to start my foreground audio service if the app is closed but the music is still playing (otherwise the music will be paused).
So I've to catch when the app is in background (like when you click the android-home-button) or when you are closing the application (for example when you click android-back-button).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So this is how I solved (to emulate the Google Music Player behaviour)

As I said I was looking for 2 kinds of event:

- when my app goes in background
- when user tap androd-back-button and goes to the android home (app is destroyed)

So this is my onPause done in my super activity

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        boolean bg = MusicUtils.isApplicationSentToBackground(this);
        if ( bg ) {
            MusicUtils.startForegroundMusic(this);
        } else {
            if ( isBackPressed ) {
                //MusicUtils.getActiviesApplicationInBackStack(this) <= 1
                if ( isBackPressed && (this instanceof DashBoardActivity || MusicUtils.getActiviesApplicationInBackStack(this) <= 1) ) {
                    MusicUtils.startForegroundMusic(this);
                }
            }
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
```

First of all I check if the app is in background with isApplicationSentToBackground (the source code in the question body).

If the app is not in the background there are 2 reasons:

- The activity is still in the foreground so the onPause it's called because we're starting a new activity or we're changing orientation (i need to skip this event)
- The app is going to be destroyed (so the same for the activity) and I need to catch this event in order to start the foregroundMusic

So to catch the second event I check if the user pressed the back button

```
private boolean isBackPressed = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            LogHelper.i(TAG, "BACK PRESSED EVENT");
            isBackPressed = true;
        }

        // Call super code so we dont limit default interaction
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

And if they bakc-key is pressed I check if this activity is the latest one (so after the current activity is destroyed my app will be destroyed!)

To check this I get the count number returned by MusicUtils.getActiviesApplicationInBackStack(this)

```
    public static int getActiviesApplicationInBackStack(final Context context) {
    int count = 0;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService( Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    List<RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfoList =  am.getRunningTasks(10);
    Iterator<RunningTaskInfo> itr = runningTaskInfoList.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        RunningTaskInfo runningTaskInfo = (RunningTaskInfo)itr.next();
        if ( runningTaskInfo.topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName()) ) {
            count += runningTaskInfo.numActivities;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

I hope this answer help someone in my same problem :) I know that this is a strange scenario but it's always a good think to share problems, thoughts and code :)

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want that? What does "in the background" mean to you? From an activity perspective your app is either active (e.g. OnResume has been called), it's paused (OnPaused has been called) or it is dead (OnDestroy has been called).

In the paused state you shouldn't be doing any work generally. You're app is paused, getting out of the way for different apps that need the system resources.

If you need to assure that something is running in the background, then you most likely need a service, although it's usually bad form to use a service which is running for a long time in the background, unless you are building something like a music player for example.

So based on your comment you are building a music player. Now a music player has two modes:

1. Either a user is interacting with it while music is playing
2. Music is playing in the background.

It makes sense to use a service for music playback so that it can run independently of the task of controlling the music player (the activity). The activity will be destroyed when the user hits back and it will get paused when the user hits the home button, or gets a phone call, locks the screen etc.

Now it's easy to detect these situations. If the activity is paused this means that the user is doing something else. You should then make sure that your music keeps playing. Android supplies [startForeground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) for this purpose, meaning that the system will kill it only as a last resort. So on the OnPause of your activity you should notify the service and put it in foreground mode, which will also show the notification.

You can do the same for the case when a user is done with your activity from OnDestroy.

Only thing left then is to make sure you call [stopForeground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopForeground%28boolean%29) when your activity is started again in OnResume.

I recommend you read up on Android architecture to know how the different components and life cycles work. Again, there should be a reason to check if your app is "in the background" in the way that you are trying to do now.

Comment: Good question botteaap . I'm developing a Music Player and I'm trying to follow the Google Music pattern. When you are playign a song and you are in the application Google Music is not showing the Notification of the played song. When you click home button (google music app is in background) it shows the notification. I've done this but the problem is still there when you click the back-button and you return to the android home screen. In this case my app doesn't goes to background as you can see...

Comment: I've edited my answer, hope it helps. You could also take a peek at the Android source code for the music app to see how they do it there.

Comment: botteaap I'm already using the source code of the music player as playground / study and infact everything works fine. But andoid music player (the old one) is starting the notification when a song is played and not when a song is played and the app is in background and it's a huge waste of resources and time. as I said I'm already checking in my onPause with that method and it's working when you click the home button but onPause and onDestroy are called always when an activity is destroyed and an activity is destroyed when you go back or when you are traversing your app inside.

Comment: [CONTINUE] So my problem is: I have to know if in onDestroy (called only when you do back and you are exiting from the app) my app is going in background because if I'm in onDestroy and my app in not in background it's because I'm going inside my app and opening another activity.

Comment: Your logic is flawed, but if you really need to know that you can set a flag when launching the new activity so you know there's nothing to be done in OnDestroy.

Comment: I've to do everything in the onPause because as said in the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html The foreground lifetime of an activity happens between a call to onResume() until a corresponding call to onPause(). During this time the activity is in front of all other activities and interacting with the user. An activity can frequently go between the resumed and paused states. ---- I'm wondering why there's no precise intent to tell my app that it's in background...

Comment: There is no concept "in the background" for an Activity, either your user is interacting with your activity or not. When your app hits the OnPause it might be paused and in the background, and it also might be killed soon after and never come back. The isFinishing method will give you in onPause if the Activity is terminated or just paused. But even in that case it might still be destroyed later.